# Can I use puppeeter to take full page screenshots + include pagination for 15K webpages?

Tags: google-chrome-headless

I'm looking to take screenshots of 15K webpages which I would otherwise want to manually visually review. If I'm able to gather screenshots of these, it will make my job much easier.

While I understand taking multiple screenshots with Puppeteer is possible, I'm also wanting to take FULL PAGE screenshots; and ideally include any additional Paginated pages within the same file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: yes, you can. I'm not sure about performance, but there isn't any technical limitation to achieve what you want with puppeteer.

The long answer: it might be a little tricky to do it nice and clean. Also, it requires some skills to make it resistant to errors. It'd be good as well to have some kind mechanism of retrying randomly failed processes. However, the simplest implementation would be:

1. Store those 15k webpages somewhere like in .csv file or database collection or so on.
2. Load all the records in your application in some structured way like as a list of the class instances like below:

```js
class WebpageProcess {
  private status = 'NOT_STARTED';
  
  public url;
  
  constructor(url) {
    this.url = url;
  }
  
  public function setSuccess() {
    this.status = 'SUCCESS';
  }
  
  public function setFailure() {
    this.status = 'FAILED';
  }
  
  public function getStatus() {
    return this.status;
  }
}
```

3. Navigate to each of the webpages iteratively, one by one, await until the page is fully loaded and make the screenshot.
4. If it's needed rename a file, or tag it, or add metadata.
5. If a process succeeded change the status to `SUCCESS`.
6. If a process failed marked it `FAILED`.
7. In the end, generate a report saying how many processes failed and list down all of them.

To make a screenshot you must use a method `page.screenshot()` with the flag `fullPage: true`. Documentation: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagescreenshotoptions

However, some of the people on the Internet complains the feature doesn't always work well. Instead, it's recommended to use the npm library `puppeteer-full-page-screenshot` that solves the problem. You must play with it yourself and check whether it works for you or not.